# Issue related with 'scorers', when trying to load a spacy NER model

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm having issues with spacy when trying to load the NER model:

```
nlp = spacy.load("./output_model/model-best")
```

It prompts the following error:

```
RegistryError: [E892] Unknown function registry: 'scorers'.

Available names: architectures, augmenters, batchers, callbacks, cli, datasets, displacy_colors, factories, initializers, languages, layers, lemmatizers, loggers, lookups, losses, misc, models, ops, optimizers, readers, schedules, tokenizers
```

I had a similar error before, and I was able to fix it by doing:

```
pip install -U spacy
```

The same code was working properly yesterday, I wonder if there is a conflit of versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After several trials, when restarting the kernel and doing `pip install -U spacy` again, it actually solved the problem.

Comment: Anything specific you did other than reinstalling? I am facing the same problem and reinstalling didn't solve :(

Comment: Hi @FarhanAhmedWasim, I was running it on a Kaggle kernel. I restarted several times and at one point it worked. Maybe try to reinstall spacy, or change the version. Hope you can fix it!